# Product Images Low Quality After Updating From WP 3.5 to 4

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, thumbnails, woocommerce-offtopic

I recently updated my WP website from WP 3.5 to recent version 4 and now I am getting a lower quality of all product feature images. I am using woocommercee to generate an online shop and it was working perfectly(HD thumbnails image qualities), I also updated the woocommerce plugin but still getting low quality images on the products

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide example of original image and resized result? Does it happen with regular (non–WooCommerce) uploads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me. I installed a [thumbnail regenerater plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/), this seemed to do the job for me.